# kotlin wait and notify

Tags: многопоточность, kotlin

Куда делись методы wait и notify в Thread?

Структура такая:

```
while(!isInterrupted)
{
th.wait(delay)
}
```

Отдельно, в главном потоке делается th.notify, что-бы предвременно запустить итерацию цикла снова. НО в kotlin не нашел ни wait, ни notify...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `Kotlin` нет этих методов у базового класса `Any`.
Это как бы намек, что нужно делать по другому.

Вот хороший ответ по теме:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520583/why-there-are-no-concurrency-keywords-in-kotlin

Если все-таки хочется `wait` и `notify`, создаете

```
private val lock = java.lang.Object()
```

И используете его методы для этих целей.

Оф. документация говорит, что можно еще использовать приведение к типу `java.lang.Object`:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#waitnotify